# Can I link 2 admob id in 1 Application with 2 different admob account?

Tags: admob

I have one android application and I want to add 2 admob id with different account in application. Can I do like that?

Answer (score 0):

From a technical point of view it should be possible, but speaking about policy, you're supposed to have only 1 AdMob account.

ALSO, as i understand, It's a violation to use multiple admob(adsense) accounts with the same account type(individual or business) and payee name.

According to their policies

"If you want to apply for more than one AdSense account

Publishers are only allowed to maintain one AdSense account under the same payee name.

However, we've provided some guidance below that may help you if you're trying to submit multiple applications. Please identify which common reason best describes your situation, then follow the instructions below.

4) I need a separate account for my business

In this case, you may submit a new application. Please make sure that the account type (individual or business) and payee name are different from your original application, and ensure that you can accept payments to that payee."